# Python literature relevant to QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, references

[Python for ArcGIS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589482824) is a book that I have been looking at. Does anyone know if this would be applicable in QGIS? I am not looking to write application/plugins, simply get better at understanding expression etc. for standard workflow. e.g. queries and data-defined settings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Original: This is coming soon: **The PyQGIS Programmer's Guide**: http://locatepress.com/ppg

Update 2019: There is a second edition out now: http://locatepress.com/ppg3

Answer (score 18):

The **PyQGIS cookbook** is a great resource

https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: I'd say barely adequate rather than "great"  :-\

Answer (score 6):

While this book is not specifically QGIS and Python, it was written for open source coding using GDAL and OGR with Python: http://www.packtpub.com/python-geospatial-development/book

Answer (score 1):

The **PyQGIS 101 tutorial** aims to help GIS users to get started with Python programming for QGIS 3:

https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/